# print specific snps alleles details from XML file

Tags: perl

I am new perl user, I have the following lines in a file

```
<Ss ssId="76536062" handle="AFFY" batchId="52074"
    locSnpId="AFFY_6_1M_SNP_A-8397107" subSnpClass="snp" orient="forward" 
    strand="bottom" molType="genomic" buildId="130" methodClass="hybridize" 
    validated="by-submitter">
    <Sequence>
        <Seq5>TCACCTCTGGGACTGA</Seq5>
        <Observed>C/T</Observed>
        <Seq3>AATTAGGAAGAGCTGG</Seq3>
    </Sequence>
</Ss>
<Ss ssId="104807776" handle="KRIBB_YJKIM" batchId="60510"
    locSnpId="KHS1200112" subSnpClass="snp" orient="forward" strand="bottom"
    molType="genomic" buildId="130" methodClass="hybridize"
    validated="by-submitter">
    <Sequence>
        <Seq5>
             TAGGAACAAGGTACATTCGCGGGATAAATGTGGCCAAGTTTTATCTGCTGCCAGGGCTTTCAAATAGGTTGACCTGACAATGGGTCACCTCTGGGACTGA
       </Seq5>
       <Observed>C/T</Observed>
       <Seq3>
          AATTAGGAAGAGCTGGTACCTAAAATGAAAGATGCCCTTAAATTTCAGATTCACAATTTT
       </Seq3>
   </Sequence>
</Ss>
```

---

I wan print the content between the both observed which is C/T. Also, I want to print just 30 bp for both seq5 and seq3. 
Thanks in advance. Any idea to help me

Comment: Try `XML::Twig` Have a read of this gentle introduction for processing SNP data  http://people.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/Twig-intro.html

Comment: I mean 30 base pair which is CTGTGCCGTATATA

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and explain the problems you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new()->parse( \*DATA );
foreach my $sequence ( $twig->get_xpath('//Sequence') ) {
    foreach my $element ( $sequence->children ) {
        print $element ->tag, " => ", $element->trimmed_text, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<root>
<Ss ssId="76536062" handle="AFFY" batchId="52074"
    locSnpId="AFFY_6_1M_SNP_A-8397107" subSnpClass="snp" orient="forward" 
    strand="bottom" molType="genomic" buildId="130" methodClass="hybridize" 
    validated="by-submitter">
    <Sequence>
        <Seq5>TCACCTCTGGGACTGA</Seq5>
        <Observed>C/T</Observed>
        <Seq3>AATTAGGAAGAGCTGG</Seq3>
    </Sequence>
</Ss>
<Ss ssId="104807776" handle="KRIBB_YJKIM" batchId="60510"
    locSnpId="KHS1200112" subSnpClass="snp" orient="forward" strand="bottom"
    molType="genomic" buildId="130" methodClass="hybridize"
    validated="by-submitter">
    <Sequence>
        <Seq5>
             TAGGAACAAGGTACATTCGCGGGATAAATGTGGCCAAGTTTTATCTGCTGCCAGGGCTTTCAAATAGGTTGACCTGACAATGGGTCACCTCTGGGACTGA
       </Seq5>
       <Observed>C/T</Observed>
       <Seq3>
          AATTAGGAAGAGCTGGTACCTAAAATGAAAGATGCCCTTAAATTTCAGATTCACAATTTT
       </Seq3>
   </Sequence>
</Ss>
</root>
```